# Runtime error while accessing an array for some specific cases

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, runtime-error, prime-factoring

I have the following code to generate **prime factors** of a number. It is working fine with all the numbers except some. The error I am getting in these numbers is **runtime error** which is at line 5 and line 10, **when trying to access *'factors'* array**.

and also why is it not giving error when accessing 'factors' array in line 15 and 18.
*This is working perfectly for numbers both greater and lesser than 48598496894, just not for 48598496894.

```
void getfactors(unsigned long long n){
    unsigned long long *factors,i=0,k=0;

    //array to store prime factors//
    factors=(unsigned long long *)malloc(n*sizeof(unsigned long long));

    //getting 2's which are factors of the number//
    while(n%2==0){
        factors[k++]=2;  //line 5
        n=n/2;
    }

    //getting other prime factors of the number//
    for(i=3;i<=sqrt(n);i=i+2){
        while(n%i==0){
            factors[k++]=i;  //line 10
            n=n/i;
        }
    }

    //last prime factor of number//
    if(n>2)
        factors[k++]=n;  //line 15
    printf("%d\n\n",k);

    //printing all factors//
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        printf("%llu\n",factors[i]);  //line 18
}
int main()
{
    getfactors(48598496894);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does debugging tell you? Is, possibly, the literal number `48598496894` interpreted as a negative number?

Comment: @Jongware - in any case, why am i getting runtime error when trying to access factors array?

Comment: check `sizeof(size_t)`

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking that factors is not `NULL` after the `malloc` in case the allocation fails. You also need to call `free` to release the memory that you allocated once you're done with it. It would also help if you commented your code to explain your intended behaviour.

To solve your problem I'd recommend checking your array indexing whilst debugging. It might be easier if you used a smaller input value to begin with until you know that your algorithm works.

One other point is whether you need the factors array at all? If the purpose of the function is to print the prime factors, couldn't you just print them as you find them?

**Edit**

I think @BLUEPIXY has hinted at the issue in the comments. The input argument to `malloc` is a `size_t`. On my PC `size_t` is a 32 bit value. If that's the case on your platform then the size of the block of memory you're trying to allocate is too big. Check if `(n*sizeof(unsigned long long)) > SIZE_MAX`. As I mentioned earlier, could you just print the factors as you find them and do away with the array?

Comment: @sclarke8-- I have commented the code. This is working perfectly for numbers both greater and lesser than 48598496894, just not for 48598496894.

Comment: Thanks for commenting the code. I've updated my answer; I hope it helps.

Comment: @sclarke9- Actually, i need to first print the number of the prime factors then the factors themselves, for that purpose i have to store the factors somewhere.... And size can not be the issue, because as i said, code is working fine for numbers both less than and greater than 48598496894.